# Parsing root-level elements out of HTML fragment file

Tags: javascript, html, parsing

I have the following code written in NodeJS, using the `parse5` library. It's purpose is to parse out the root-level elements in a file containing HTML fragments (Vue component files). I want the inner content of these root-level elements to remain unchanged.

I attempted several times to use `cheerio`/`htmlparser2`/`parse5` to parse the file as HTML, but always with some sort of undesirable side-effect to the inner content of the root-level elements.

Finally, I decided to make an attempt at some custom parsing (but not from scratch, because that would be stupid, hence using the SAXParser in `parse5`. Right now it handles a few hundred test cases, but I'm afraid there are plenty more edge cases that are going to come back and bite me.

Can anyone here see any pitfalls with this code? Is there a simpler way of accomplishing this that's more robust?

```
var parse5 = require("parse5")

const parse = module.exports = (str) => {
  const parser = new parse5.SAXParser({ locationInfo: true })
  const elements = []
  let current = null
  parser.on('startTag', (name, attrs, selfClosing, location) => {
    const tag = { name, attrs, openingTag: location, count: 0 }
    if(current){
      if(current.name === tag.name) current.count++
      return
    }
    current = tag
  })
  parser.on('endTag', (name, location)=>{
    const tag = { name, location }
    if(!current || current.name !== tag.name) return 
    if(current.count > 0) current.count--
    else{
      current.closingTag = tag.location
      elements.push(current)
      current = null
    }
  })
  parser.end(str)
  return elements.map((element)=>{
    delete element.count
    const attrs = {}
    element.attrs.forEach((attr)=>{
      attrs[attr.name] = attr.value !== '' ? attr.value : true
    })
    element.attrs = attrs
    element.content = str.substring(element.openingTag.endOffset, element.closingTag.startOffset)
    return element
  })
}
```

Here is an example (vue component) HTML file:

```
<template>
  <div class="blurb">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <img :src="$foo('bar')" />
    <p v-if="showDescription">Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
module.exports = {
  el: '#blurb',
  data(){
    return {}
  },
  mounted(){

  },
  methods: {
    $foo(){
      return 'image.jpg'
    }
  }
}
</script>
<style lang="less">
.blurb{
  h1{
    color:blue;
  }
}
</style>
```